# SQL full text query only working for first keyword

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I'm not an expert on FULL TEXT search so I kind of googled around for an SQL query **SORTED BY RELEVANCY** and came up with this which is somewhat working:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(fulltext_tags) AGAINST ('+blue' '+red') AS relevance FROM `products` WHERE MATCH(fulltext_tags) AGAINST ('+blue' '+red' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

The problem is, only the first keyword is taken into account.
Say I have this Product table

```
+----------+------------------+
|   name   |  fulltext_tags   |
+----------+------------------+
| Product1 | Blue             |
| Product2 | Red              |
| Product3 | Blue Red         |
| Product4 | Yellow           |
+----------+------------------+
```

The above query only returns product 1 and 3, it is completely ignoring the second keyword '+red'. Even adding +Yellow as third keyword still ignores it, so it ignores anything past the first keyword...

How do I make it so a query with +blue and +red returns Product1 Product2 and Product3 since at least one or both keywords are figuring in the fulltext_tags field ?

Thanks

Comment: By default full-text indexing ignores words 3 letters long or smaller.

Comment: Please remove the duplicate, this question's answer has nothing to do with the 3 letter keyword "red" used in the query. I specifically stated that even using Yellow it still doesn't work so the problem is not with the 3 letter  keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `REGEXP '[[:<:]]Red[[:>:]]'` for find exact word, so try below query hope it will work and fulfill your requirement.

```
SELECT * FROM `products` 
  WHERE fulltext_tags REGEXP '[[:<:]]Red[[:>:]]' 
  OR fulltext_tags REGEXP '[[:<:]]Blue[[:>:]]';
```

You can see [DEMO Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc080/1).

**Update 1**

Try This Query, As I can observe you want to do something like this,

```
SELECT *, 
      MATCH(fulltext_tags) AGAINST ('+blue' '+red')     
      AS relevance FROM `products` 
  WHERE MATCH(fulltext_tags) AGAINST('Red') 
      OR MATCH(fulltext_tags) AGAINST('Blue')
  ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

See here [ONLINE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68aaf/15)

Comment: Hi, this is still unsuable, only a FULL TEXT query with match() against() will return results based on relevancy...

Comment: @Flames, I updated my answer with SQLFiddle so check once.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try this and get back to you!

Comment: THANK YOU Piyush, this worked like a charm, exactly what I needed the query now takes into account all keywords and is sorted by relevancy. THANKS so much!!! :)